# PHP: How to get time of session entry and page exit

Tags: php, forms, session, time

I am trying to create a page for a small experiment for my dissertation. I have to measure when a person opens an experimental page and when closes it.

After reading some other questions, I came up with an idea to get the time when the session starts and when a person clicks the button to proceed to another page in a form. Like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['timeEnt']= date('H:i:s');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<form method="post" action="name.php">
<input type="hidden" id="date" name="timeExt" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" onclick="document.getElementById('date').value = new Date(<?php date('H:i:s')); ?>" />
</form>

</html>
```

Unfortunately, later when I get the results I see that the time value in *timeEnt* is taken from the server and in *timeExt* from a PC. Another problem is that timeEnt shows a normal format: HH:MM:SS; while timeExt shows e.g. Sat Mar 07 2015 HH:MM:SS GMT+0100

Is there a way to get both from the server and in the same format (HH:MM:SS)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either use frontend or backend exclusively to avoid any conversion issues:

```
<?php
$sTimeEnt = date('H:i:s');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<form method="post" action="name.php">
<input type="hidden" id="date" name="timeEnt" value="<?php echo $sTimeEnt; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>

</html>
```

And in name.php

```
<?php
$aPost    = $_POST;
$sTimeEnt = $aPost[ 'timeEnt' ];
$sTimeExt = date('H:i:s');

// Compare to your liking the two.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember PHP runs on SERVER. So it's impossible to get user side datetime.

To get the user datetime. You should do it with javascript:

```
var currentTime = new Date()

document.write(currentTime.toString());
```